# How convert abitrary string into bytes without UnicodeEncodeError issue?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

I should not expect any error here. I just want to take the string literaly and translate it into its bytes. I don't want to encode or decode anything.

I am taking here a stupid example:

```
>>> astring
u'\xb0'
```

Stupid enough to give me headache...

```
>>> bytes(astring)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position...
```

One horrible trick is to do this:

```
>>> bytes(repr(astring)[2:-1])
'\xb0'
```

One other bad solution is:

```
>>> bytes(astring.encode("utf-8"))
'\xc2\xb0'
```

It is a bad solution because my string is not composed of two chars. This is wrong.

Another awful solution would be:

```
>>> bytes(''.join(map(bytes, [chr(ord(c)) for c in astring])))
'\xb0'
```

I am using Python 2.7

**Background**

I would like to compare two columns on a database where the encoding is unknown and sometime conflicting. I don't care about wrong chars on my dump. I just want to get it to have a look at it.

Comment: You should always mention the Python version you're using for Unicode questions. What do you mean "translate it into its bytes"? Unicode strings are sequences of codepoints, not of bytes. If you want bytes, then you need to perform an encoding.

Comment: If I load a string into memory it is a sequence of raw binary data. I should be able to dump it into bytes anytime no matter the content.

Comment: But a Unicode string _isn't_ a string of bytes! Sure, at the hardware level, everything is bytes (well, really it's machine words, but let's not get distracted ;) ), but thinking of a Unicode string as if it's a string of bytes is not useful. In Python 3 the distinction between bytes and text is a lot clearer, in Python 2 things are not so clear, and this can lead to various forms of confusion.

Comment: I _suspect_ that you may be able to get the bytes you want by encoding your Unicode data to Latin1. `u'\xb0'.encode('latin1')` works (in both Python 2 & 3), but I can't guarantee that it will do what you want with other data that may be present in your Unicode strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Unicode strings are guaranteed to only contain codepoints < 256 then you can convert them to bytes using the Latin1 encoding. Here's some Python 2 code that performs this conversion on all codepoints in range(256).

```
r = range(256)
s = u''.join([unichr(i) for i in r])
print repr(s)

b = s.encode('latin1')
print repr(b)

a = [ord(c) for c in b]
print a == r
```

**output**

```
u'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
True
```

FWIW, here's the equivalent Python 3 code.

```
r = range(256)
s = u''.join([chr(i) for i in r])
print(repr(s))

b = s.encode('latin1')
print(repr(b))
print(list(b) == list(r))
```

**output**

```
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬\xad®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ'
b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
True
```

Note that the Python 3 Unicode repr output is a little more human-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just 'take the string literally' because the actual, internal, bytes representation of your string is not fixed and is an implementation detail of the your python interpreter that your should not rely on (see [PEP3993](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393-flexible-string-representation), on the same system different string can use different internal encoding).

That also means that to get a byte representation of you string, you really need to encode it, and thus specify the encoding.

By the way, `astring.encode("utf-8")` is not wrong (and already returns a `bytes`, you don't need the extra `bytes(...)` in your code), as in utf-8 a single character can be represented as several bytes.

Comment: But I doesn't work in anycase. I fall wither in a `unicode` error or an `ascii` error. In this particular case the `.encode('utf8')` solve the issue, but in other case I would need to put `.encode('ascii')`. Moreover if I do encode an unicode chain, I will double the encoding...

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean. You will not double any encoding : it translates from the internal encoding (which is hidden and should not matter to you) to utf-8. Do you have a case where `.encode('utf-8')` does not work ? why would you need to use .encode('ascii') in some case ? an ascii string can always be encoded in utf-8

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to just add `b` before the quotes of the string.

```
>>> astring = b'\xb0'
>>> astring
b'\xb0'
>>> bytes(astring)
b'\xb0'
>>>
```

Putting `b` before the string makes it a `bytes` object.  No more `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question, my `u'\xb0' is just an example here